# How do you register/unregister handlers to the event used in Observable.FromEventPattern?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm getting an IObservable from Observable.FromEventPattern, as shown below:

```
SomeObject target = new SomeObject();
string eventName = "SomeEvent";
IObservable<T> obs = Observable.FromEventPattern<T>(target, eventName);
```

From what I understand, the FromEventPattern call will automatically generate add/remove event handlers for me. But when does the handler actually get added/removed?

I assume that the handler is added when the IObservable is subscribed to. Is the handler also automatically unregistered when the subscriber is disposed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy enough to just write up a simple test yourself to see when `Observable` uses the add/remove handlers by simply supplying your own handlers that cause side effects:

```
var observable = Observable.FromEvent(
    action => Console.WriteLine("Added"),
    action => Console.WriteLine("removed"));

Console.WriteLine("Subscribing");
var subscription = observable.Subscribe(unit => { });
Console.WriteLine("disposing");
subscription.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine("done");
```

This prints out:

```
Subscribing
Added
disposing
removed
done
```

Telling us that subscribing invokes the add handler, and disposing the subscription object removes the handler.

In the event that you have multiple subscriptions to the observable, then the handler will be added any time you subscribe to an observable that has no previous subscriptions, and disposing of a subscription only removes the handler if it was the last remaining subscriber.  This can be seen by modifying the test to create multiple subscriptions and then disposing of them all.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware those other overrides did that. So does that mean that if you do not dispose the subscription and it goes out of scope then it still keeps a strong reference to the event (and potentially causes leaks?)

Comment: @fred Yes. It's common to keep a collection of disposables around using [CompositeDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.compositedisposable.aspx).

Comment: @fred The observable object is going to have a reference to whatever is being observed, and what is being observed holds a reference to the observable so long as the event is attached, this is a circular reference.  This means that the GC can't ever reclaim one if the other is rooted.  Now if *both* the observable *and* the observed object's lifetimes have ended then *both* can be reclaimed.  You only have a problem on your hands if you're holding onto a reference to one and you want the other to be able to be freed, in which case you need to "unlink" them.

Comment: @Servy This isn't the whole story. Rx 2.0 included an optimization that allows multiple subscriptions to share the same event handler, thus subsequent calls to `Subscribe` and all calls to `Dispose` except for the last call will have no observable effect.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/20/reactive-extensions-v2-0-release-candidate-available-now.aspx

Comment: @DaveSexton Yes, that's exactly what I would have expected, but it's worth being explicit about; I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, this has been very helpful.